# Microsoft Visual Studios C++ Default Windows Desktop Application

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When creating a new project on Windows Visual Studio using C++, one of the options for a default template is the Windows Desktop Application.  What libraries does this utilize?

I just started learning C++. I don't know what a DLL vs a LIB is, but I just need a name of the correct library so I can do research via YouTube into how to use it.

Comment: Do you mean dynamic libraries (DLLs) or static libraries (LIBs)? The latter sometimes wrap the former, but not necessarily. Do the built-in Windows API libraries count?

Comment: Stub libraries for WinAPI and either dynamic or static runtime support libraries (depends on compilation options).  Are you asking what you need to distribute with your application ?

Comment: " I just need a name of the correct library so I can do research via YouTube into how to use it.". You'd be better off reading the official documentation than watching a video of someone's interpretation of it.

Comment: Do you really need to know **all** the libraries?  I think you would only need to know the functions on how to draw windows, intercept and pass messages.  MS Visual Studio is trying to make life easy for you by hiding all the libraries for you.  Remember, there a a bunch of drawing libraries (at the pixel level) that you don't need to know at your level.  You may want to investigate GUI frameworks for C++.  Most of the good frameworks have tutorials.

Comment: ***What libraries does this utilize?*** You can see them listed in the linker settings. Look at `Linker->Command Line` section of your project.

Comment: This is a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/walkthrough-creating-windows-desktop-applications-cpp?view=msvc-170) for a desktop application that I recommend you read. And refer to drescherjm's suggestion.